# How can select future date randomly without csv in jmeter from the list

Tags: date, jmeter

I have this list of date. i need to select only any future date from the list without csv. how can i do this?

[Image of list of date](http://screencast.com/t/ag5dGvfsMwB)

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: [HTML Link Parser](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTML_Link_Parser) - see [Poll Example](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#poll_example)

Option 2: Combination of [XPath Extractor](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) and [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) function

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use **${__time(dd,)}** to get current date. This date will be in **String format**. Lets store this to variable name **date**
2. Convert this date in number with java script function **parseInt** in BSF pre processor. Lets store this to variable name **date_int**
3. Now with random function **${__Random(${date_int},30,)}**, you will get random number between current date and 30th of the month.
4. Use this random number for selecting index of your date list.

Answer (score 0):

[code is here](http://screencast.com/t/zH7MbPzn9)
This is working here.
I have putted the myDay,myMonth,myYear variables as parameter.